# How to get argLine to work in maven surefire plugin

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, surefire

I'm having difficulty trying to add an argument to the jvm.  It looks like using surefire is the only way to do this.  My current code in the pom.xml is

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.19</version>
   <configuration>
       <argLine>-Xmx512m</argLine>
       <systemPropertyVariables>
          <all.clusters>${all.clusters}</all.clusters>
          <branding.token>${brandingToken}</branding.token>
       </systemPropertyVariables>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Maven is new to me so perhaps I'm missing something simple.

Running in a Netbeans 8.1 environment.

Comment: And what is the issue with this configuration? Apart from the fact that the `version` is incorrect, it looks ok.

Comment: It doesn't work.   According to my logging I get the following messages. Input arguments:
 -Xms24m
 -Xmx64m
 -XX:MaxPermSize=384m

Comment: Can you post the relevant Maven logs, in debug mode (`-X`), when `maven-surefire-plugin` is invoked?

Comment: No sure how to do so.  I'm running in netbeans and not from the cli.

Comment: It appears that just having surefire in the build section is not enough. Researching how to make sure it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that what I needed to do was not to get surefire to run with special arguments, because that only covers tests.  The trick to getting it working was the fact that this project is a NetBeans application which uses the
nbm-maven-plugin.

The following blog post describes how to modify the arguments.
[Blogpost](https://netbeansscribbles.wordpress.com/2013/11/27/changing-vm-options-for-netbeans-rcp-applications/)